# Excel right function picking date

Tags: excel

I need to pick year and month from the below string separately. Kindly suggest
09-Feb-2010. I have tried few right options but its giving me incorrect results

Comment: If your date is in A1 then `RIGHT(A1,4)` and `MID(A1,4,3)`

Comment: Hi Tim I tried the first option for year but it gave me result as 0218

Answer (score 0):

The excel function `=TEXT(value, format_text)` should work here as you are working with a formatted date. You can therefore format the date for year with `"yyyy"` or for month with `"MM"`, an example for just year below:

[image]